# Firebase assign recieved data to variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I was working on a web app and previously noticed that Firebase didn't let me do things like this but was able to find workarounds, but it would be much easier if I could get queries like the following to operate the way I want them to:

```
var testString='asdf';
firebase.database().ref('testing').once('value', function (snapshot) {
  testString=snapshot.val();
  console.log('Data val: ' + snapshot.val());
});
console.log('Val after: ' + testString);
```

When run, this gives me the console output of:

```
Val after: asdf
Data val: testval
```

Instead of what I would have expected:

```
Data val: testval
Val after: asdf
```

It looks like the Firebase listener doesn't execute the query when it's called. I looked through the documentation, but I didn't find anything that would help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase SDK APIs that fetch data are all asynchronous.  The [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method is asynchronous, meaning it returns immediately while another thread actually performs the fetch.  It returns a promise that resolves when the work is complete.  You can't change the way this works - you have to use asynchronous programming techniques.  You can expect that the next line of code after the call to once() will execute immediately, before the asynchronous work is done.

What you have to do instead is put the code that deals with the snapshot entirely inside the callback.  Or, you can use the returned promise to trigger some code, which is also effectively a callback to a function.  These are your only options.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't understand the suggestion to trigger code with the returned promise, though are there any examples of this you could point me to?